# Select by attribute expression invalid in python

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, sql, select-by-attribute

I'm not sure how my expression is failing. Any ideas?

```
inPoints = "points.shp"
i = 0
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inPoints, "pts")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("pts", "NEW_SELECTION", '\"FID\" = i')
```

Comment: is your file path correct? do you have any errors telling you which line is failing?

Comment: The MakeFeatureLayer works fine. So the file path is right. I just get:   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6435, in SelectLayerByAttribute
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute)

Comment: Same problem: line 17, in <module>
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("pts", "NEW_SELECTION", "[FID] = i")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6435, in SelectLayerByAttribute
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Errors using SelectLayerByAttribute in ArcPy](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61499/errors-using-selectlayerbyattribute-in-arcpy)

Comment: shapefile or feature class? i believe the syntax changes depending on the type

Answer (score 7):

You need to use [string formatting](http://mkaz.com/solog/python-string-format) when inserting your counter, `i`, into the SQL query:

```
'\"FID\" = {}'.format(i)
```

As it stands now, your script is asking Arc to find an object with `FID = i`, and that does not exist.

Comment: +1. As an aside - searching for features based on an FID is bad practice as they may be missing or reassigned in some cases.

Comment: @Radar, I would agree with that.

Comment: Jason's answer does not work with Python 2.6.x. To use the string formatting in for ArcGIS 10.0 and 10.1 use the following: `'\"FID\" = {0}'.format(i)`.

Comment: @Saleika, in the case where there is only one item in the "queue", the index number may be omitted: 
`>>> print '\"FID\" = {}'.format(1)`
`"FID" = 1`
`>>> print '\"FID\" = {:0>2d}'.format(1)`
`"FID" = 01`
See the string formatting guide I've linked in my answer above. If this is not the case in Python 2.6.x, then make sure to specify the index number inside the brackets, `{}`. However, it appears that @angelspatial is using Arc 10.1 which would indicate Python 2.7.

Comment: Great! @Jason, The reason I was using FID was because it was recommended in response to another question I asked. [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58793/run-viewshed-on-only-one-feature-at-a-time-in-a-shapefile) Do you have a better recommendation on how to handle that one? Feel free to answer it there. :)

Answer (score 0):

This solution can help using str().

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("pts", "NEW_SELECTION", "\"FID\" = "+ str(i))
```

In this example, value is `int`, but expression has to be `str`, thus just convert it `str(i)`and add it to expression.

Comment: Can you please expand on your answer to explain why it could be helpful