# Runtime error : ERROR 000358: Invalid expression using SelectLayerByAttribute in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, error-000358

I cannot for the life of me persuade SelectLayerByAttribute to work (I need to automate this for a complex script).  Working in ArcMap's python console on already loaded shapefile, the format below:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:/Users/.../working"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("layer", "NEW_SELECTION", " 'ATTRIBUTE' = 'Criterion' ")
```

results in error:

> Runtime error : ERROR 000358:
>   Invalid expression Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).

An alternative method:

```
import arcgisscripting
import arcpy
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)
gp.workspace = "C://...//working"
sFile = "C://...//working//shapefile.shp"
lyr = "layer"
gp.makefeatureLayer_management(sFile, lyr)
gp.toolbox = "management"
gp.SelectLayerByAttribute("layer", "NEW_SELECTION", " 'ATTRIBUTE' = 'Criterion' ")
```

.. selects **everything**, including features that don't meet the criterion!

Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong?  I've read some pages on [this problem](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1729&t=300732), but found no solution that works here. The working directory is correct. The attribute field and criterion are correctly specified (case sensitive etc), etc. Its very confusing.

Comment: Should it be `" \"ATTRIBUTE\" = 'Criterion'"`

Comment: In case someone else is looking: this same error (000358) can also come up because of the SDE logfile settings--as described here http://support.esri.com/de/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/34539

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("layer", "NEW_SELECTION", ' "ATTRIBUTE" = \'Criterion\' ')
```

You have to take care of the escape characters.

Comment: How annoyingly simple! However just for clarity the right format for me is actually `" \"ATTRIBUTE\" = 'Criterion' "`

Answer (score 5):

Another variation that I used to use is:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("layer", "NEW_SELECTION", ' "ATTRIBUTE" = ' + " 'Criterion' ")
```

Note how the double quotes on the field name are inside single quotes, while the single quotes on the value are inside double quotes.

However, nowadays I omit the unnecessary double quotes around the field name, and simplify it to this:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("layer", "NEW_SELECTION", "ATTRIBUTE = 'Criterion'")
```

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with a similar error but just invented this:

```
for myValue in myList:
    query = "\"ATTRIBUTE\" = \'" + myValue + "\'"
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("layer", "NEW_SELECTION", query)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layer, outputName, "", "0", "0", "0")
```