# arcpy interate row, in a python script? SQL Select expression not working

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor, select, error-000358

I am creating a python script where I am trying to iterate over point feature class. I want to create seperate Feature classes from each individual day. So select daynumber and then export it to a new FC with an unique daynumber as name.

I was unable to find my answer online. So I decided to ask my question here.

ArcGIS 10.2

My script looks as follows:

```
test1 = "D:\\Mijn_Doc\\Test_Geodatabase.gd\\test1"
dayno = 2618
with test1 as rows:
    for row in rows:
        query = '"daynumber = '+ str(dayno) + '"'
        arcpy.Select_analysis(test1, 'D:\\Mijn_Doc\\Test_Geodatabase.gdb\\select'+str(dayno), query)
    dayno +=1
```

Gives the following error:

> arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression "daynumber = 2618" Failed to execute (Select)

The selection looks fine, If I build it in Model Builder and export it to a Python script the expression looks the same as it looks in this Error message.

Comment: A lot of your code looks wrong. For example, the extension to the geodatabase for your test1 variable should be .gdb, not .gd. You then appear to want to be performing a search curosor, as you are currently attempting a with statement on a string. This will throw an error. I'd look further into cursors. There should be plenty of examples here and on esri documentation http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000

Comment: I agree with Emil. See the code sample on that page which includes `with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:` to get started.

Comment: Rather than exporting a model to Python script, as a means to try and get syntax right, I think it is always better to run tools from their dialog and then go to **Geoprocessing | Results** to **Copy As Python Snippet**.

Comment: That's a good technique @PolyGeo, that way you only get *working* code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why the cursor?

Just something simple like this will work and be clean:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\ArcGIS\Default.gdb'
for dayno in xrange(2618, 2630, 1):
    arcpy.Select_analysis(test1, "{0}_{1}".format(selecttest, dayno), """daynumber = '{0}'""".format(dayno))
```

Comment: Beautiful JGP! I removed the single quotes in the select expression: """daynumber = {0}"""  and it run smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

[ERROR 000358](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00vp00000026000358.htm) is 'the expression is not valid', this doesn't help much. I think though it's similar to [Runtime error : ERROR 000358: Invalid expression using SelectLayerByAttribute in ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61499/runtime-error-error-000358-invalid-expression-using-selectlayerbyattribute-in) where the user was attempting to select a string field populated with numbers without quoting the number.

Your SQL query should be

```
"daynumber = '"+ str(dayno) + "'"
```

which when unquoted becomes:

```
daynumber = '2618'
```

The field name doesn't need to be quoted or bracketed like in 'select by attributes'; the only time that I've found the field name needs to get special quotes or brackets is in field calculator.

I'm not sure about `with test1 as rows:`, surely that should be `with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(test1) as rows:` but it's confusing what you're trying to do in the snippet. You're iterating through rows but then performing a select against the data...

Answer (score 0):

For the SQL, you have a double quote in the wrong spot.

Try:

`query = '"daynumber" = '+ str(dayno)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everybody.

I followed some of your advises and in the end this was the (working) script I was looking for:

```
dayno = 2618
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(test1, ('daynumber',)) as cursor:
for row in cursor:
    query = 'daynumber=%s' % dayno
    if dayno > 2630:
        break
    else:
        arcpy.Select_analysis(test1, selecttest + str(dayno), query)
        dayno +=1
```