# Error 000358 using SelectLayerByAttribut_management using escape characters

Tags: arcpy, select-by-location, error-000358

I am trying to use arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribut_management using the following code:

```
def filterData(self):
    self.filterBuilder()
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (r"%s\tempclipprefilter"%self.workspace, "lyr")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", '" ATTRIBUTE" = \'self.DataQuery\' ')
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("lyr", self.outFC)
```

I have also tried just

```
self.DataQuery
```

and

```
ATTRIBUTE - self.DataQuery
```

in place of

```
'"  ATTRIBUTE" = \'self.DataQuery\' '
```

I have looked at [Runtime error : ERROR 000358: Invalid expression using SelectLayerByAttribute in ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61499/runtime-error-error-000358-invalid-expression-using-selectlayerbyattribute-in) but this has not solved my issue.

The code producing self.DataQuery is below:

```
    def filterBuilder(self):
        self.queryList = []
        if self.aField == 'true':
            self.queryList.append(" myDataColumn <> 'N' ")
        if self.bField == 'true':
            self.queryList.append(" class LIKE 'R%'")
        if self.cField == 'true':
            self.queryList.append(" class NOT LIKE 'L%'")
        if self.dField == 'true':
            self.queryList.append(" class LIKE 'CI%'")
        if len(self.queryList)>0:
            self.DataQuery = self.queryList[0]
            i=1
            while i < len(self.queryList):
                self.DataQuery= self.DataQuery + " AND %s" %self.queryList[i]
                i+=1
        else:
            self.DataQuery = ""
```

What is the error in my code or my approach?

Comment: Can you post the entire code for your class that you're forming?  It's hard to debug when we can't see the full code.  Have you tried this: `'"ATTRIBUTE" =  '.format(self.DataQuery)`  You were also adding a space to the field name `ATTRIBUTE`. It may also help to add some print statements so you can actually see what the query is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will solve your issue if you specify the location to substitute `self.DataQuery` in your where statement.

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", '"ATTRIBUTE" = \'{0}\''.format(self.DataQuery))
```

Also, you can simplify the part where you build the value for  `self.DataQuery` with:

```
if len(self.queryList) > 0:
    self.DataQuery = ' AND '.join(queryList)
else:
    self.DataQuery = ''
```