# arcpy.SelectByAttribute 'Parameters are not valid' error

Tags: arcpy, point, random, iteration, error-000840

I am trying to run a python script to select 5 random points in an attribute table and to loop through every 100 points to do this. When I run the function SelectRandomByCOunt within a python shell, it works perfectly fine but I am trying to embed it in this For loop and it doesnt work. I keep getting this error mesg:

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
The value cannot be a feature class
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Layer.
ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer.
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).
```

### The code

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env

# path name of the feature class
ws = r"S:\Venu\APWRAGOEAProject\APWRAGOEA.gdb"
fcname = r"PracticePythonCode"
fc = os.path.join(ws, fcname)

# replace 'xxx' with file path

# get count of features
num = arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)
print("There are "+str(num)+ " rows in your feature class.")

# start counters
count = 0
next100 = 1

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['OBJECTID']) as scursor:  ## column 1 name [0], column 2 name [1]

      for srow in scursor: # iterate through rows

        if count < (next100 * 100):
                      col1 = srow[0] ## grab value from column 1

      # do processing of these 100 records here using col1, col2 variables
                      def SelectRandomByCount (layer, count):
                                import random
                                layerCount = int (arcpy.GetCount_management (layer).getOutput (0))
                                if layerCount < count:
                                    print "input count is greater than layer count"
                                    return
                                oids = [oid for oid, in arcpy.da.SearchCursor (layer, "OID@")]
                                oidFldName = arcpy.Describe (layer).OIDFieldName
                                path = arcpy.Describe (layer).path
                                delimOidFld = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters (path, oidFldName)
                                randOids = random.sample (oids, count)
                                oidsStr = ", ".join (map (str, randOids))
                                sql = "{0} IN ({1})".format (delimOidFld, oidsStr)
                                arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management (layer, "", sql)

                      SelectRandomByCount (fc,5)

                      # increase count by 1
                      count = count + 1

        else:

              # move to next group of 100 
                next100 = next100 + 1

del srow, scursor
```

Comment: Why is def SelectRandomByCount(Variable1,Variable2) inside your main?? In SelectLayerByAttribute your 2nd argument should be 'NEW_SELECTION' not an empty string, see https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000071000000 for more info but that shouldn't raise that error unless S:\Venu\APWRAGOEAProject\APWRAGOEA.gdb\PracticePythonCode doesn't exist, use arcpy.Exists here. When you're using a with block for your arcpy.da cursor you don't del row, cursor objects, that's managed by the with; also for portability SearchCursor(fc, 'OID@') is more universal.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have the feature class defined in my .gdb. I am not python savvy for starters :( So I found this SelectByRandomCount code on stack exchange to select random set of points out of a huge dataset but then I wanted to only select out of a certain number of points and then select from the next set as an iteration in the table so I tried to embed this code inside a For loop.

Comment: I got the function from here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78251/how-to-randomly-subset-x-of-selected-points/167826

Comment: That is a good example to start from but def Function(vars) by convention appears *outside of the main* (see https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp for some basics) otherwise the function is being created and destroyed for each iteration. Procedural languages either prefer or insist on having the functions *before the main*. Another 'gotcha' is that functions scope their own variables, if you want to use a variable defined on the main level you need to implicitly specify that with the global statement otherwise you'll have the name defined *twice* but inaccessible outside scope.

Comment: BTW This conundrum sounded familiar, I've answered a similar question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342907/randomly-subsetting-of-polygons-by-class-attributes-using-arcpy/343016#343016 previously, though the situation was more complex but might be worth a look; it's only the selection function though, not the implementation in the main.

Comment: Thank you, got it! i will take a look .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the exception states, **SelectLayerByAttribute_management** expects a layer (which is not the same thing as feature class -`fc` variable in your case, that you are passing, which is just the data) and you have to create one before passing into the def. If you use [Make Feature Layer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm) tool to create a layer just before `SelectRandomByCount` call and pass this layer into your def call, e.g., `SelectRandomByCount ("SayMyLayer",5)`, your code should run fine. However, there are many lingering parts in your code which is not related to the error that you receive!

Comment: Thank you it worked! I did this: # path name of the feature class 
fc = r'S:\Venu\APWRAGOEAProject\APWRAGOEA.gdb\PracticePythonCode'

# Make a layer from the feature class
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc,"fc_lyr")  SelectRandomByCount ("fc_lyr",5)